# Django Static Files Not Loading in Deployment

Tags: django, django-staticfiles, django-deployment

I've been going at this for about 3 hours now and I'm completely lost and running in circles. I'm trying to get my static and media files into deployment.

My settings file looks like this:

```
DEBUG = False 

...

STATIC_ROOT = '/home/huhu/webapps/eng30_static_media/static'
MEDIA_ROOT =  '/home/huhu/webapps/eng30_static_media/media'

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

I've run collectstatic and my static files are in /home/huhu/webapps/eng30_static_media/static I still have no idea what to do with the media files. What am I missing here? I currently don't have any static js, static img, static css, or media uploaded via the admin panel showing.

Comment: Nothing. Once you upload something through your site or admin, MEDIA_ROOT directory will me created and the file saved there.

Comment: You should provide more context, what is your server type, what deployment method, what web server?

Comment: Take a look at http://djangodeployment.com/2016/10/18/checklist-for-django-settings-on-deployment/ and check the web server log files at `/var/log/nginx/error.log` or `/var/log/apache2/error.log`.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using nginx, you would add the following location to your server block

```
location /static/ {
    root /home/huhu/webapps/eng30_static_media;
}
```

---

Because you have `DEBUG` set to `False`, django will not serve the staticfiles for you in production like it does on your dev server.  This is by design because, as the documentation notes, the staticfiles application is grossly inefficient and may be insecure:  https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/howto/static-files/

Answer (score 1):

Open your browser console and see the response that is returned when fetching static files.

You have to let your web server serve files. `Make sure that your web server (apache/nginx) have proper permissions to access the static directory`, which in your case '/home/huhu/webapps/eng30_static_media/static'.
If you will still be facing issues, then `move static files to /var/www/static directory if you are using apache` and change your static root to

```
STATIC_ROOT = '/var/www/static'
```

Check permissions/ownership on files using `ls -l`

```
ls -l
-rw-r--r-- 1 www-data www-data 11321 Jul 28 17:08 index.html
```

for apache `user/group www-data/www-data` must have access on files that needs to be served through server. If files are owned by others, try a `chown` on the files/directories to change ownership.

```
chown -R chown -R username:group directory
```

If you are using nginx, then `define your static files directory in nginx conf` and try reloading the page.